# SQL server 2000 pulling count grouped by time

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2000

I have a table like below.

```
   Date           |      Time    |      connect    |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 05.26.13  | 1  |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 05.32.11  | 1  |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 05.26.13  | 1  |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 06.02.52  | 1  |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 06.41.09  | 1  |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 06.43.12  | 1  |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 06.52.09  | 1  |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 06.57.39  | 1  |

2013-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 03.58.35  | 1  |

2013-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 04.02.18  | 1  |

2013-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 04.12.02  | 1  |

2013-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 04.41.36  | 1  |

2013-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 11.12.27  | 1  |

2013-10-22 00:00:00.000 | 11.58.35  | 1  |
```

I want to get the count of connect that fall in each hour, grouped by date. 
Count falling between 1:00 to 1:59, 2:00 to 2:59 and so on. The below is model of the output that I require.

```
Date   | Count(between 4.00.00 to 4.59.59)  | Count(between 5.00.00 to 5.59.59) | Count(between 6.00.00 to 6.59.59) |Count(between 11.00.00 to 11.59.59) |

2013-08-23 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 3 | 5 | 0 |

2013-10-21 00:00:00.000 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

2013-10-22 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use group by with the date time functions if you don't care about missing 0 row counts, but if you are concerned, use the tally table example Jeff mentions in 2nd page of this forum post: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic288581-8-1.aspx  Both examples in this post, but it note it is by half hour, should be easy to convert to hour.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I want.

by Matt Watson

SELECT [Hourly], COUNT(*) as [Count] FROM (SELECT dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, '20010101', [date_created]), '20010101') as [Hourly] FROM table) idat GROUP BY [Hourly]